# Why can't I use table aliases here?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, syntax, sql-server-2008-r2

For some reason I cannot assign the table alias `t` to the first set of tables in the `FROM` clause. I want to call this `t` and then `LEFT JOIN` to the other set of tables. Why can't I do this?

```
select
    job.job
from 
    (job
inner join 
    item on job.item = item.item
inner join 
    jobroute as jb on job.job = jb.job and job.suffix = jb.suffix) as t --the error message points to this line
left join 
    (select
         jb.job, jb.suffix,
         sn.notecontent
     from
         SpecificNotes as sn
     join
         ObjectNotes as onn on onn.SpecificNoteToken = sn.SpecificNoteToken
     join
         jobroute as jb on jb.RowPointer = onn.RefRowPointer) as x on t.job = x.job and t.suffix = x.suffix
```

Comment: You need a `Select column names From Job... ` if you want to alias that as `t`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you just remove the `as` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are only used to group the joins.  You don't create an additional alias off of them.

They are generally unnecessary.  So, remove them:

```
select j.job
from job j join
     item i
     on j.item = i.item join
     jobroute jr
     on j.job = jr.job and j.suffix = jr.suffix left join
     (select jb.job, jb.suffix, sn.notecontent
      from SpecificNotes sn join
           ObjectNotes onn
           on onn.SpecificNoteToken = sn.SpecificNoteToken join
           jobroute jr
           on jr.RowPointer = onn.RefRowPointer
     ) x
     on t.job = j.job and t.suffix = j.suffix;
```

You are probably a little confused because parentheses are also used for subqueries and these *require* table aliases.  However, merely grouping joins is not an opportunity for an alias.

You'll also note that I removed the `as`.  This is a personal preference.  I find that `as` simply clutters the `from` clause, but it is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    job.job
from 
    (select
        job
    from
        job
    inner join 
         item on job.item = item.item
    inner join 
        jobroute as jb on job.job = jb.job and job.suffix = jb.suffix) as t --the error message points to this line
    left join 
    (select
         jb.job, jb.suffix,
         sn.notecontent
     from
         SpecificNotes as sn
     join
         ObjectNotes as onn on onn.SpecificNoteToken = sn.SpecificNoteToken
     join
         jobroute as jb on jb.RowPointer = onn.RefRowPointer) as x on t.job = x.job and t.suffix = x.suffix
```